# Validating if the meta_key already exist

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to validate if the meta_key in wp_postmeta already exist, if the metakey already exist, it will used the update_post_meta, if not it will used add_post_meta. I cant make it work, seems like a logical error with my codes, any help?

```
if(isset($_POST['submitHoliday']))
{

    global $wpdb;

        $holiday = $_POST['holiday'];
        $cMonth = $_POST['country_month'];
        $cYear = $_POST['sortYear'];

        $timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
        $maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
        $thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
        $startday = $thismonth['wday'];

        for ($i=0; $i<$maxday+$startday; $i++) 
        {

            if($i < $startday) continue;

            $date = $cYear."-".$cMonth."-".($i-$startday+1);
            $event = $holiday[$i-$startday];

            if($event != NULL AND !get_post_meta($_POST['country'], $date))
            {

               add_post_meta($_POST['country'], $date, $event);

            }
            else
            {
                update_post_meta($_POST['country'], $date, $event);
            }
        }   

}
```

Comment: Why not just use `update_post_meta` in all cases?  From [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta): "This may be used in place of add_post_meta() function. The first thing this function will do is make sure that $meta_key already exists on $post_id. If it does not, add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value) is called instead and its result is returned."

Comment: `if($event != NULL){ AND !get_post_meta($_POST['country'], $date))
            {

               add_post_meta($_POST['country'], $date, $event);

            }
            else
            {
                update_post_meta($_POST['country'], $date, $event);
            }

Comment: @MagentaCuda the null values are saving, I already tested that. Thanks.

Comment: Ignore previous.` if ($event != NULL) {
    if (!get_post_meta($_POST['country'], $date)) {
        add_post_meta($_POST['country'], $date, $event);
    } else {
        update_post_meta($_POST['country'], $date, $event);
    }
 }`